# Adding IoC Support to my WCF service hosted in a windows service (Autofac)

Tags: wcf, windows-services, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'd like to setup my WCF services to use an IoC Container. There's an article in the Autofac wiki about WCF integration, but it's showing just an integration with a service hosted in IIS.

But my services are hosted in a windows service.

Here I got an advice to hook up the opening event 
http://groups.google.com/group/autofac/browse_thread/thread/23eb7ff07d8bfa03

I've followed the advice and this is what I got so far:

```
    private void RunService<T>()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new DataAccessAdapter("1")).As<IDataAccessAdapter>();

        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(T));

        serviceHost.Opening += (sender, args) => serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(
            new AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior(builder.Build(), typeof(T), ??? ));                      


        serviceHost.Open();
     }
```

The AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior has a ctor which takes 3 parameters. The  third one is of type `IComponentRegistration` and I have no idea where can I get it from. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written a blog post that describes how to use the Autofac WCF Integration when Self-Hosting WCF Services.

http://alexmg.com/self-hosting-wcf-services-with-the-autofac-wcf-integration/

That should be enough to point you in the right direction. I am going to update the documentation on the Autofac wiki to include the same example.

Comment: Looks great!! I will try it out tomorow. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in Autofac since the Alex Meyer response. It's basically one line of code:

```
//Instead of
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior(container, typeof(EchoService), registration));
//Use this
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<IEchoService>(container);
```

Source: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/wcf.html#self-hosting